# How to call non existing method with flexmock

Tags: python, mocking

Lets assume class:

```
class Something():
    def first(self):
        return None
```

I need to replace this class with Mock object but I need to call or add nonexisting attribute to it. When I try

```
fake = flexmock(Something, new_method=lambda:None)
```

I receive `AttributeError`.

Is it possible to add non existing attribute or method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a non-existing attribute to an object or class is as easy as `something.new_attr = some_value` or `setattr(something, 'new_attr', some_value)`. To add a non-existing method to an object or class, just call one of the following functions:

```
def add_method(target, method_name): 
    """add class method to a target class or attach a function to a target object"""
    setattr(target, method_name, types.MethodType(lambda x:x, target))
def add_instance_method(target, method_name):
    """add instance method to a target class"""
    setattr(target, method_name, types.MethodType(lambda x:x, None, target))
```

Now, `add_method(Something, 'new_method')` will add a (dummy) class-level 'new_method' to class `Something`, `add_method(something, 'new_method')` will add a 'new_method' to object `something` of type `Something`(but not for other instances of `Something`), `add_instance_method(Something, 'new_method')` will add a instance-level 'new_method' to class `Something`(i.e. available for all the instances of `Something`).

Note: the above doesn't work for instances that has not `__dict__` attribute(e.g. instance of built-in class `object`).

Please check the other question on stackoverflow:  [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)